# VBA Visio - how to run macro when shape is changed

Tags: vba, visio

I have a VBA code in Visio that will change the color of the shape if said shape is hyperlinked.  Right now, I run it by using a simple command button.  I want the macro to run when a change occurs in the worksheet. I know in excel if I wanted to do that I would simply place my code in the Workbook_Change sub, but in Visio I am lost.

Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Sh As Visio.shape
Dim Link As Hyperlink

For Each Sh In Visio.ActivePage.Shapes  '<~ loop through the shapes collection
For Each Link In Sh.Hyperlinks      '<~ loop through the links collection
    If Not Link.Address = "" Then   '<~ check for a blank address
        Sh.Cells("Fillbkgnd").Formula = "RGB(255,102,0)"
        Sh.Cells("Fillforegnd").Formula = "RGB(255, 102, 0)" '<~ apply a color to the shape
    End If
Next Link
Next Sh

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

@JonFournier I have revisted this and here is my code that lives in ThisDocument:

```
Public WithEvents Pg As Visio.Page

Private Sub Pg_CellChanged(ByVal Cell As IVCell)
Set Pg = Pages("Page-1")
If Cell.Section = visSectionHyperlink Then
    Dim Sh As Visio.shape
    Dim Link As Hyperlink

    For Each Sh In Visio.ActivePage.Shapes  '<~ loop through the shapes collection
        For Each Link In Sh.Hyperlinks      '<~ loop through the links collection
            If Not Link.Address = "" Then   '<~ check for a blank address
                Sh.Cells("Fillbkgnd").Formula = "RGB(255,102,0)"
                Sh.Cells("Fillforegnd").Formula = "RGB(255, 102, 0)"    '<~ apply a color to the shape
            End If
        Next Link
    Next Sh
Else
End If
End Sub
```

The code that I put inside works perfectly fine when paired with a command button, but I would like it to work when the shape is changed.  What else should I add to the code to "instantiate the object" or to get it to run the way I need it to.  I can't seem to get anything to work.  Appreciate the help.

Again, I am sorry this is appearing as an answer, my work firewalls will not allow me to comment for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the CellChanged event on the Page object, and check if the changed cell is in the hyperlink shapesheet section.

In a class module:

```
Public Withevents Pg as Visio.Page

Private Sub Pg_CellChanged(ByVal Cell as IVCell)
    If Cell.Section = visSectionHyperlink Then
        ' call your code here
    End If
End Sub
```

You would need to instantiate the object and keep it alive to monitor your active page, but this is the general gist of something that would work for you, I think.

This would also live happily in ThisDocument, if you'd prefer that.

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I apologize that it is taking me this long to reply.  The firewalls at my work do no allow me to respond to posts made on stackoverflow.  

I have tried manipulating your code to achieve what I was trying to do, but still with no luck.  If I figure out the solution, I will let you know.